# H2O Steam public R code

Tags: r, h2o

In H2O Steam Overview: Data scientists can publish Python and R code as REST APIs and easily integrate with production applications.

I don't know how to public R code as REST APIs in H2O steam.
Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t publish R or Python code as REST services, but you can create REST services from POJOs and MOJOs.

For instructions and examples, see https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder